# What is the role of the Op-Amp integrator in this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverter, multisim, integrator, class-ab

[image]

Helo dier community! I got a 400 Hz broken Power Inverter and reverse-engineered the circuit just for the simplicity of repairing it.
Then I got deeper in and started to understand the engineering principle of the circuit. But I em stuck on this Op-Amp integrator build in and his role in this circuit. It would be nice if you could help me to understand his role. If you need some Voltage references I can provide it. The circuit is a simulation in Multisim and fully running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the integrator output on p10 ought to be near 0V if the NPN PNP gains are matched with transients expected on start/stop of loads in order to balance the primary coil from saturation. it does this by balancing the input voltage drop to the transformer input R+impedance.  A saturated core presents a very low impedance.  This occurs on startup often.

Record all the DC voltages and compare with simulation and paste results on schematic if you cannot debug.

Answer (score 0):

The integrator ensures minimal DC current through the output transformer T1. The Vos of the OP-07 is maximum 150uV so the DC current will be less than 150uV/0.01 ohms or 15mA.

The output amplifier is DC-coupled so this is necessary to keep the transformer from saturating.